# Isotope Height doesnt change with content

Tags: jquery, css, resize, height

I have been working on a isotope container and have had a bit of trouble getting the height to stay dynamic to the content.

I have added options to my container like `reLayout`, resizeable true but dont seem to get it working.

I have noticed that my container is getting a height style injected into it but havent figured out from where, youll notice in my video the only way i have been able to get the height to fit my content is to set a height on one of the divs (`col_1`) within the isotope, the container seems to get that height injected into it but doesn't resize with the other tabs. Ive fiddled all day and night with the css yesterday to try and solve this one but im stumped.

Heress a jing video of my issue: 
http://www.screencast.com/t/Zq1giEtdt

This is the website:
http://daniloportal.com/NPC/howitworks.html

Also, here is a snip of my isotope js

```
//Isotope sorting
 var $container = $('.projects');

 $container.isotope({
    filter: '.sort_category1',
    resizesContainer: true,
    resizable: true,    
  });

  $('.projects').isotope('reLayout')

  var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

  $optionLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
        key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[ key ] = value;
    if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
      // changes in layout modes need extra logic
      changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
    } else {
      // otherwise, apply new options
      $container.isotope(options);
    }

    return false;
  });
```

});

Any help is appreciated, Thanks interwebs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after much confusion i figured it out. I had too man height styles that were set for Col_1 all i did was eliminate those styles and the isotope now sets all the height paramaters dynamically! :D